# Stripe Deferred Account Activation

Tags: c#, stripe-payments, stripe-connect, stripe.net

I am trying to create a user using Stripes Connect Api following the Deferred Account Activation 
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/deferred-accounts

I am providing the request with what I believe is what is known as the "Platform_Secret_Key" which I think is found in the dashboard's Account Settings > Connect > Platform Settings > ClientId

When I use this in my request as the 'apiKey' I get "Invalid Api Key" error.

However, if I use my account ApiKey, as suggests here https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_account
it errors too with 
"You cannot use this method on your own account: you may only use it on connected accounts."

Has anyone been successful? How is this done?

Comment: I found the answer. The API endpoint for working with connected accounts is /v1/accounts where I was using the endpoint for personal account /v1/account

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your platform's secret API key (found in the [API keys tab](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys) of your dashboard). The client_id (found in the [Connect tab](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/applications/settings)) is used to connect standalone accounts via the [OAuth flow](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts#oauth-flow) -- this doesn't apply here since you're directly creating accounts (aka "[deferred accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/deferred-accounts)"), not going through the OAuth flow.

Simply using the [create account](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_account) API endpoint with your platform's secret API key should work. Unfortunately I'm not sure if Stripe.net supports this. The documentation mentions support for the OAuth flow but not for deferred accounts or managed accounts. You might have better luck asking directly on the GitHub tracker for the project: https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net, or maybe someone else will have a better answer for you here!